# Solve a system of three equations in three variables to find all fixed points of this system.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Solve a system of three equations in three variables to find all fixed points of this system.
>   \begin{align}
> x &= 0.7x + 0.1y + 0.3z \\
> y &= 0.1x + 0.3y + 0.3z \\
> z &= 0.2x + 0.6y + 0.4z \\
> \end{align}

An answer provided at the back of the textbook is:
$$(x, y, z) = (0.429, 0.214, 0.357)$$

I'm not sure how to get to that answer. Can someone point me in the right direction, as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: Collect like terms.  You have a homogeneous system of linear equations to solve.

Comment: The book should provide the answer as fractions, which are exact, instead of decimals.  If the coefficients are approximate numbers the solution should not have three places.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Note that the columns of coefficients on the right hand side are nonnegative and add up to one.  So likely this problem comes up in a discrete math context about Markov transition matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
3x - y - 3z &= 0 \\
x - 7y + 3z &= 0 \\
x + 3y - 3z &= 0
\end{align}
These can be converted to the form $AX = B$ where
$$A = \left[
\begin{matrix}
3 & -1 & -3 \\
1 & -7 & 3 \\
1 & 3 & -3
\end{matrix}
\right],
B = \left[
\begin{matrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{matrix}
\right],
C = \left[
\begin{matrix}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{matrix}
\right]$$
$A$ can be converted to the reduced row echelon form by performing Gaussian elimination on it such that
$$A = \left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & -\dfrac65 \\
0 & 1 & -\dfrac35 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}
\right]$$
From this, it follows that for any value of $z$,
$$\begin{align}
x - \dfrac65z &= 0 \implies x = \dfrac65z \\
y - \dfrac35z &= 0 \implies y = \dfrac35z
\end{align}$$

Let $z = 0.357$, then $x = \dfrac65\cdot0.357 \approx 0.429$ and $y = \dfrac35\cdot0.357 \approx 0.214$, i.e., $(x, y, z) \approx (0.429, 0.214, 0.357)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the equations from the problem can be rewritten to what you provided?

Comment: Collect like terms. You can get rid of the decimal because it is common in all coefficients.

Comment: thank you, an4s. I was able to use the method you provided to solve the next, similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: your system is equivalent to
$$-3x+y+3z=0$$
$$x-7y+3z=0$$
$$x+3y-3z=0$$
Multiplying the second equation by $3$  and adding to the first:
$$-20y+12z=0$$
Doing the same with the last equation:
$$10y-6z=0$$
And from these equations we get:
These two equations are the same so $$y=\frac{3}{5}z$$ and $$x=\frac{6}{5}z$$

Comment: When you do the last equation it should be $-6z$ and the two equations are dependent.  You cannot conclude that $z=0$.

Comment: Yes you are right, it is just corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Your equations are linearly dependent so you really only have two equations in three unknowns.  There will be a solution that can be multiplied by any constant to get another solution.

\begin{align}
x &= 0.7x + 0.1y + 0.3z \\
y &= 0.1x + 0.3y + 0.3z\\
z &= 0.2x + 0.6y + 0.4z\\
0&=-0.3x+0.1y+0.3z\\0&=0.1x-0.7y+0.3z\\0&=0.2x+0.6y-0.6z\\
y&=0.6z\\x&=1.2z
\end{align}
An any multiple of $(1.2,0.6,1)$ is a solution.

Comment: Note that the "book answer" given in the Question has components that add up to one, reinforcing the interpretation as a steady state probability distribution.